# Understanding add_to_heap(+Heap0, +Priority, ?Key, -Heap)

Tags: prolog, heap, swi-prolog

From the [docs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/heaps.pl):

> **`add_to_heap(+Heap0, +Priority, ?Key, -Heap)`** is semidet
>
> Adds `Key` with priority `Priority` to `Heap0`, constructing a new heap in `Heap`.

If I understand it correctly, then `add_to_heap` adds a key and its priority to `Heap0`, and then adds `Heap0` to `Heap`. So `Heap` is basically a box of heaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Prolog is a *declarative* language. That means that - aside from *further* grounding - **once a variable has a value, you cannot change that value anymore** (by backtracking you can *undo* that, but in that case you lose of course the context of the previous call path). So you **cannot add a key to an existing heap**.

As a result declarative languages construct *new* structures. For instance `append(A,B,C)` will construct a *new* list `C` that is equivalent to `A` followed by `B`. Another example is a [*finger tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree).

That is also how this predicate works: you **construct a new heap** `Heap` that is equal to `Heap0`, but the difference is that the `Key` is added with the given `Priority`. As a result you can still use the old `Heap` as well.

For instance:

```
demonstrate_use_old :-
    empty_heap(H0),
    add_to_heap(H0,0,foo,H1),
    heap_size(H0,0),
    heap_size(H1,1).
```

This thus tests that the first *empty* heap `H0` still has size 0 after adding `foo`. `foo` is only added to a new heap `H1` (which has size 1).

You may - justly - say that constructing new datastructures is computationally expensive. That's why declarative languages usually have a set of dedicated datastructures - for instance, Haskell and Prolog by default use a (linked)list instead of an array because this allows adding to the head in *O(1)*. A *finger tree* is a tree-like datastructure that allows fast push/pop/inspect/...